# Date diff compare now time to date started

Tags: php, calculator, datediff

I have A simple calculation that works out compound rate interest on a savings, account.

**Simple calculation**

```
    $p = 300; // Starting amount
    $i = 0.06; // Interest rate
    $c = 12; // compound frequency set to monthly
    $n = 2/12; // Current time invested set to 6 months
    $r = 200; // Monthly investment is 200

    $x = $i / $c;
    $y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));

    if($p!=0)
    {
        $vf = $p * $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);
    }
    else
    {
        $vf = 1 + $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);
    }

    echo $vf;
```

The problem is I need a variable that determines the age of the account, so I created date diff code comparing the now time to the date the account was opened.

**Date diff code**

```
    $join_date = $row->start_date;  // 8th jan 2015
    $date1 = new DateTime('now');  // 9th march 2016
    $date2 = new DateTime($join_date); ?>

    $n = (int)$date1->diff($date2)->format("%m");  // 2 months
```

So if I use this code for the variable $n then the answer should the the same as the original code its not.

The code without modification gives answer ***704.00749999999*** (correct)

the modified code gives ***5424.53898108*** (wrong)

So the question is dose anyone know whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your own script, you set

```
$n = 2/12;
```

but the modified code sets

```
$n = (int) $date1->diff($date2)->format("%m"); // == 2
```

And obviously, `2/12 !== 2`, so maybe it should have been

```
$n = ((int) $date1->diff($date2)->format("%m")) / 12;
```

Comment: Yep, head slap time. been reformatting my code and missed a obvious mistake ... thank you @Matteo Tassiniri